# I want to read the inputs from two list box and to display the output

Tags: matlab, user-interface, listbox

I have two list boxes in my GUI.

each will display the string values.

User will select the inputs from listbox and will click on OK push button.

Now i have my data set in xls file with three columns.

INPUTS which is entered by the user will get compared with excel sheet column values.

Once it find a match with two inputs from the listboxes, then it has to display the 
corresponding 3rd column value as output

**EXAMPLE:**

abc one FIRST ROW
zzz two SECOND ROW
aaa three   THIRD ROW
vvv four    FOURTH ROW
www five    FIFTH ROW

**if i select "abc" and "one" from listbox1 and 2 respectively then the output is "FIRST ROW"**

Comment: please help me on this question....iam not able to paste the table or picture....So my question is unclear....In Simple way read the inputs from the listbox and compare the inputs with textdata and display the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need the handles of both list-boxes. Lets say they are stored within myLB1 and myLB2.
2. You get the whole bunch of data of each listbox by:

   `myData1 = get(myLB1,'String');
    myData2 = get(myLB2,'String');`
3. Now you get the selected indices by:

   `myInd1 = get(myLB1, 'Value');
    myInd2 = get(myLB2, 'Value');`
4. Finally you get the selected data by:

   `mySelDat1 = myData1(myInd1);
   mySelDat2 = myData2(myInd2);`

-> now you can compare the data. Look for the type of your data! Could be a cell-array...

Comment: Type of the Data is String.